# Network edgelist issue- only data on participants, can't add in attributes

Tags: r, networking, nodes, network-analysis, edge-list

I have network data (cellphone data) from participants in a study, and I'm trying to make a network with this data, but since the edgelist is made up of just participants connecting with other random people, when I use attributes from the participants to add color, etc. to the network visualization, it doesn't apply correctly because it thinks it should apply to all nodes (since the left-hand column is made up of participants, and the right hand is all the random people they called, the random people in the right-hand column are taking on the same attributes as the participant).
I was able to find a workaround for coloring the nodes based on being a participant or not using another person's question (code below), but I can't figure out how to use the attributes (e.g. average call length, number of calls) to change parts of the visualization due to the way the edgelist is set up. Is there another way to do this??

code workaround for coloring the nodes based on being a participant:

```
plot(
  BE_1, 
  vertex.label=NA, 
  vertex.color=ifelse(degree(BE_1, mode = "out")>0, "red", "black"),
  vertex.size=ifelse(degree(BE_1, mode = "out")>0, 15, 4),
  edge.arrow.size=.1
)
```

I've tried `vertex.size=` based on different attributes, but that hasn't worked, so here I've just set up the non-participants to be smaller.

Comment: Need a complete example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description your edgelist looks something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
el <- 
  tibble(
    from = sample(1:10, 30, replace = TRUE),
    to = sample(11:200, size = 30),
    duration = runif(30, 3, 200)
  ) |> 
  # adding edges between participants
  bind_rows(
    tibble(
      from = c(5, 9),
      to = c(7, 3)
    )
  )

el
#> # A tibble: 32 × 3
#>     from    to duration
#>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     3    74    108. 
#>  2     7   164    125. 
#>  3     3    87    165. 
#>  4     3    43    188. 
#>  5     8   103     73.5
#>  6     7   144    143. 
#>  7     5   198    167. 
#>  8     3   143     97.4
#>  9     5   183    122. 
#> 10    10   125     44.2
#> # ℹ 22 more rows
```

Create a data set that describes the participants by aggregating the edgelist.

```r
nodes_participants <- 
  el |> 
  group_by(from) |> 
  summarise(avg_dur = mean(duration),
            n_calls = n(), # same as out degree.
            # this will allow us to differentiate between participants and non-participants
            participant = TRUE) |> 
  rename(name = from)
```

nodes_randos contains the names/ids of the non-participants. We need this
because `igraph` requires
the nodes dataset to contain all nodes.

```r
nodes_randos <- 
  el |> 
  distinct(name = to) |> 
  mutate(participant = FALSE) |> 
  # filter out participant edges
  filter(!name %in% nodes_participants$name)
```

Create `nodes` dataframe

```r
nodes <- 
  bind_rows(nodes_participants,
            nodes_randos) |> 
  replace_na(list(avg_dur = 0, n_calls = 0))
```

Create `igraph` object

```r
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(el, directed = TRUE, vertices = nodes)

# This is how we can calculate vertex measures and add them to the graph.
V(g)$out_degree <- degree(g, mode = "out")
```

#### Some igraph plotting examples.

```r
plot(g,
     vertex.label=NA, 
     vertex.color=ifelse(V(g)$participant, "red", "black"),
     vertex.size=V(g)$out_degree,
     edge.arrow.size=.1)
```

[image]

```r
plot(g,
     vertex.label=NA, 
     vertex.color = ifelse(V(g)$participant, "red", "black"),
     vertex.size = sqrt(V(g)$avg_dur),
     edge.arrow.size=.1)
```

[image]

```r
plot(g,
     vertex.label=NA, 
     vertex.color = ifelse(degree(g, mode = "out")>0, "red", "black"),
     vertex.size = V(g)$n_calls,
     edge.arrow.size=.1)
```

[image]

#### `ggraph` plotting example.

`ggraph()` takes care of scaling the node size.

```r
library(ggraph)

ggraph(g, layout = "nicely") +
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = participant, size = avg_dur))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful! The only issue I'm running into is that participants can also call each other, so the list of non-participants is still including some participants. I tried going through and just deleting the actual participants from the non-participant list, but then realized the duration + number of calls will be off since it was based on the participants being in the 'from' column, so it's not including the duration/call for participants in the 'to' column- do you know of a workaround here with the code? Otherwise I can just correct it manually

Comment: I modified my answer to include participant-to-participant edges. The only change is to filter out the participants from the random node `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! :) You are a life saver!!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider accepting/upvoting it.